# Split Command - Choose Output Name

Tags: python, bash, split

I have a text file named `myfile.txt`. The file contains 50,000 lines and I would like to split it into 50 text files. I know that this is easy with the split command:

```
split myfile.txt
```

This will output 50 1000-line files: xaa, xab, and xac.

My question, how do I run split my text file so that it names the output files:

```
1.txt 
2.txt
3.txt

...

50.txt
```

Seeking answers in python or bash please. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Here is a potential solution using [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) to get the chunks and string formatting for the different file names:

```
from itertools import islice

with open('myfile.txt') as in_file:
    for i in range(1, 51):
        with open('{0}.txt'.format(i), 'w') as out_file:
             lines = islice(in_file, 1000)
             out_file.writelines(lines)
```

Answer (score 1):

its not exactly what you are looking for, but running

```
split -d myfile.txt
```

will output

```
x00
x01
x02
...
```

Answer (score 1):

To generate test data in empty directory, you can use

```
seq 50000 | split -d
```

To rename in the way that you want, you can use

```
ls x* | awk '{print  $0, (substr($0,2)+1) ".txt"}' | xargs -n2 mv
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a funny one: if your `split` command supports the `--filter` option, you can use it!

If you call

```
split --filter=./banana myfile.txt
```

then the command `./banana` will be executed with the environmental variable `FILE` set to the name `split` would choose to write the chunk it's processing. This command will receive on its standard input the chunk being processed. If this command returns a non-zero status code, then split will interrupt its operations.

Together with the `-d` option, that's exactly what you want. With the `-d` option, the name split will choose for the filenames will be `x01`, `x02`, etc.

Make a script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# remove the leading x from FILE
n=${FILE#x}
# check that n is a number
[[ $n = +([[:digit:]]) ]] || exit 1
# remove the leading zeroes from n
n=$((10#$n))

# send stdin to file
cat > "$n.txt"
```

Call this script `banana`, `chmod +x` it and let's go:

```
split -d --filter=./banana myfile.txt
```

This `--filter` option is really funny.

Comment: What version supports `--filter`? It doesn't seem to be supported by either the BSD `split` included with Mac OS X 10.10 or GNU `split` included with GNU coreutils 8.4.

Comment: @chepner `split (GNU coreutils) 8.21`. I just discovered this funky option by reading the `man` page. Nifty trick.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how you could split this file in bash:

```
split -l 1000 -d --additional-suffix=.txt myfile.txt
```

The `-l` argument determines the number of lines included in each split file (1000 in this case, for 50 total files), the `-d` argument uses numbers instead of letters for the suffixes, and the value we pass to the `--additional-suffix` argument here gives each file a `.txt` file extension.

This will create

```
x00.txt
x01.txt
x01.txt
```

etc.

If you wanted to change the 'x' portion of the output files, you'd want to add a prefix after the input file (e.g. `myfile.txt f` would create `f01.txt`, `f02.txt`, etc.)

Note that without `--additional-suffix`, your files will all lack filename extensions.

I've looked to see if there's a way to split a file and name them with *only* the suffix, but I haven't found anything.

Answer (score -1):

A simple approach:

```
f=open('your_file')
count_line,file = 0,1
for x in f:
    count_line +=1
    if count%1000 == 1:
        f1 = open(str(file) + '.txt','w')
        f1.write(x)
        file +=1
    elif count_line%1000 == 0:
        f1.write(x)
        f1.close()
    else:f1.write(x)
```

Comment: Not my downvote but whether this works or not, this is really poorly written code.